# Mercurial subrepo with secret phases: avoiding inconsistent host repo state

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

Assuming the following situation:

1. I have a mercurial "host repo" with a subrepo.
2. The subrepo contains a changeset in the secret phase.
3. The "host repo" has a changeset in the draft phase that depends on the secret-phase changeset in the subrepo.

If one now pushed the "host repo", the draft-phase changeset from the "host repo" gets pushed while the secret-phase changeset from the subrepo does not get pushed.

The pushed-to repo thus now contains a state to which one cannot update: it depends on the secret-phase changeset from the subrepo which was not pushed and is thus not available.

Is it possible to prevent mercurial from pushing the host repo changesets that depend on secret-phase subrepo changesets? (Possibly with hooks or some configuration setting.)